# How to manipulate files in external hard drive using terminal?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, gnome-terminal

How can I access (remove to be specific) files from my external hard drive which is already mounted using terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it via `/media/[username]/[crazy characters]`

`[username]` is your username logged in
`[crazy characters]` is random things, mine was "7856-2D7D"

Comment: On older systems like 12.04 removable media is by default mounted directly under `/media` without a subdirectory for the user.